# @KafkaListener and one single Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have this method

```java
@KafkaListener(topics={"one", "two", "three"})
public void listen(String message) { ...}
```

How can listener container instantiate only one single Consumer independently from topics and partition.

For example, if I have these partition:

```
one-0
one-1
two-0
three-0
three-1
```

There is a way for assigning all these partition to the same single Consumer?
Is `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`'s concurrency value to 1 enough for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats's exactly what you'll get by default (with concurrency=1, default).

Watch for the INFO log `Partitions assigned ...`.

Comment: Ok, now, what's not clear to me is if partitions are create explicitly or if not there is always one partition per topic.

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of commenting, when it is unrelated. If the broker is configured to allow automatic topic creation (`auto.create.topics.enable`), the number of partitions is determined by the `num.partitions` broker config (default 1). With Spring, you can create topics by adding `NewTopic` `@Beans`, where you can specify how many partitions you want (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#configuring-topics). Or, you can create topics with the `kafka-topics.sh` command line tool.